# Permission Denied (publickey) Error in Visual Studio Code for a GitHub Repo Despite Proper SSH Setup

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm facing an issue when trying to push or pull from a GitHub repository using Visual Studio Code (VSCode). Here are the details of the problem:

1. I am a collaborator on a GitHub repository, and I have the proper
   permissions.
2. I've successfully cloned the repository using SSH, and I can pull
   and push from the terminal without any issues.
3. I've ensured that I've set up my SSH key properly, and it works fine
   in other contexts.
4. However, when I attempt to pull/push from VSCode, I encounter the
   following error message: "Git: git@github.com: Permission denied
   (publickey)."

I've done some research and found similar threads discussing this issue, but none of the solutions seem to apply to my situation. Furthermore, I can't even write the SSH key code in VSCode, as the error message appears before I can input it.

I'm looking for assistance in resolving this specific issue with VSCode, as it seems to be unrelated to the standard SSH setup or repository permissions. Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.